# ReactJS Router- How to use history push within function component with parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having problems using `history.push("path/...")` within a function component. My problem is when i try to use a function component's param in the button handler. I have the next code:
`Example.js`

```
...
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
...

//This function works fine, but i would prefer something reusable
function Button() {
    const history = useHistory();
    function handle(){
        history.push("/path"); //The path is harcoded
    }
    return(
        <button onClick={handle}>
            Home //This text is harcoded
        </button>
    );
}

//This is what i'm looking for, because i would write it once.
function Button(path, text) {
    const history = useHistory();
    function handle(){
        history.push(path); //This doesn't work
    }
    return(
        <button onClick={handle}>
            {text} //This throws an error "no valid react child"
        </button>
    );
}

//this component is being render as a child of BrowserRouter
class Example extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Button path="path/..."/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export ...
```

This is my actual code, just removed repeated lines. With the first function component i have no problems, but, I'm in the need to create a new function component for every button. Instead i'm looking for a way to write this functions once and use it to create many buttons.

The second function does nothing when the path is being passed through props, and if I add `console.log(path)` in the `handle()`, the path value is printed as it is passing correctly, but `history.push(path)` does not take it.

I want to add that, the only clue I have is the push method documents, where the types this method takes are `string`, but `any` is being passed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React components receive only a single argument that is the props object. You are assuming two.

```
function Button(path, text) {
  const history = useHistory();
  function handle(){
    history.push(path); // This doesn't work
  }
  return(
    <button onClick={handle}>
      {text} // This throws an error "no valid react child"
    </button>
  );
}
```

should be

```
function Button({ path, text }) {
  const history = useHistory();
  function handle(){
    history.push(path); // This should work now
  }
  return(
    <button onClick={handle}>
      {text} // This should render now
    </button>
  );
}
```

Notice here the passed props are destructured from the `props` object.

Answer (score 0):

Send path and name as props and use those inside your button function.

```
<Button path="path/..."/ name="Home">

function Button({path,name}) {
    const history = useHistory();
    function handle(){
        history.push(path); 
    }
    return(
        <button onClick={handle}>
           {name}
        </button>
    );
}
```